# English test feedback insufficient for improving

Tags: grammar, word-usage, vocabulary

I have been through [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/), [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/), and [Writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/), and from "*what topics can I ask about here?*" and some meta/post discussions at each site about reviewing some writing skills, it seems to me that this is the most proper site (after posting it in Writing and being told that here was a better fit). Besides, I don't consider my question looking for a proofreading service as stated in [this accepted answer in meta writing](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/304/56407) defines proofreading as "*a technical act of correcting obvious mistakes and no more*". Which to me the answer to my question is no obvious at all and I can't find the answer using online translators (because my answer was done straight from English). Given that justification for posting my question, let's go to the question itself:

I have done an English writing skill online test, and I have received this feedback:

> - Coherence and cohesion: High - The text is well organized, logical, and meets the task requirements. Uses a variety of cohesive devices
>   appropriately.
> - Grammar, usage and mechanics: High - Uses technical words and complex verbs to explain the idea.
> - **Lexis (vocabulary): Medium - Presents a few spelling, punctuation, and/or minor grammatical errors, but the grammar structure can
>   improve.**
> - Typos: High - Doesn't present any typos.

I'm interested in the **bold** sentence. I don't see how could I improve my text on that. What spelling, punctuation, minor grammatical errors, and grammar structure should I improve? What are the mistakes? The test questions are in **bold** and my answers are in

> Blockquotes

**Question 1: Imagine you're working on an important project, but due to several reasons, you will be unable to deliver it within the established deadlines. Compose an email to your manager explaining the situation and why you need a new date. Use as many words as you consider necessary to be clear with the message you want to communicate.**

> Hi [Manager's name],
>
> As you may know, we have had some problems with the project.
> Specifically:
>
> 1. The data is not structured as it was accorded in the beginning. Hence
>    the ML model in production won't be consistent.
> 2. There are some
>    important features for the ML model that aren't available at the
>    moment we need to do the prediction. This implies that we need to
>    iterate again with the model construction in order to use only the
>    features available at the moment of prediction. The business partner
>    gave me his official confirmation with the manager responsible for the
>    data of a list where we can choose features.
> 3. The data team is still
>    doing consistency tests on the data. As I used their deadline as input
>    to set this project's deadline, I can't assure data consistency for
>    the model given the current deadline.
>
> For these reasons, I would like to ask you for a new deadline. My
> proposal would be to push the deadline in 3 weeks, given that:
>
> 1. We will know in the current week what data is properly structured,
>    which would allow us to develop smoothly the model without
>    inconsistencies.
> 2. We have confirmation from the business partner and
>    the CTO for the availability of the features.
> 3. The data team has to get
>    done the data tests the next week and add one week more as a safe
>    measure. We would still have one week left to develop the model.
>
> Do you agree? Do you have any thoughts on this matter? Hope to hear
> from you.
>
> Regards,
>
> Chris

**Question 2. Tell us about something you firmly believe and how you would convince others to believe the same. Use as many words as you consider necessary to be clear with the message you want to communicate.**

> I think that artificial intelligence (AI) will change the shape of the
> world. For me, it's not a question of if it's going to change the
> world but when. AI performs human tasks with much less probability of
> error, a huge of them are from the manual labor market (e.g.
> construction, delivery services, etc.) and everything that relates to
> performing manual and repetitive tasks. Why? Because repetition is
> automatable and once is automatic the task is performed with minimal
> error vs a human. The last gap that AI needs to overcome is consumer
> confidence. It doesn't feel the same that a person cooks your burger
> as for a machine to do it. Once that gap is removed, AI will take
> every corner of the labor market.

So, what do you guys think? Is the feedback accurate? If it's, where or how could I improve? Do you see a pattern in the mistakes where I could focus on?

Comment: I feel like this is still a proofreading question. Sure, you may just want us to somehow just point out the nature of the mistakes, but that still requires every answerer to find all mistakes. For what it's worth: I agree with the feedback you received. I also still will VTC this. But maybe someone more experienced with all three SEs can help you along. Otherwise, there's always the chat, and I'd certainly be willing to help you there. Good luck!

Comment: @Joachim I agree that a complete answer would require detailed proofreading. Furthermore, an optimal answer would need to distinguish between true errors and stylistic defects. Nevertheless, there is a middle ground. The majority of the errors involve word choice. That can be demonstrated through examples.

Comment: There are definitely some semantic  and structural issues. For example: "This implies that we need to iterate again with the model construction" would sound better like this: "This implies we need to re-iterate the construction model" etc. You need to take an English writing course. And yes, this is basically an editing question so it really should be closed...

Comment: Sadly I agree with the above comments, it is proofreading by another name. Also, as can be seen in the comments to the answer below, subject to opinion or personal preference. Therefore I too am going to VTC, but I've also upvoted the question for effort as it does raise some interesting questions. I presume you want the corrections to be to BrE or similar standard and you don't have access to a suitably qualified native BrE speaker who you might ask to look at the work for you.

Comment: I can see a few errors, which I don't want to list.  It seems to me that the best way to improve would be to expose yourself more to good English.  Read more.  Listen to news broadcasts and documentaries.  Have more conversations with native speakers.

Comment: " What spelling, punctuation, minor grammatical errors, and grammar structure should I improve?"  All of them.  That is the only possible answer in the scope of this site.  We can't go through your text looking for the mistakes, that is your teacher's job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The feedback that you received seems quite fair to me although not perhaps as understandable as it might be.

You have a small number of grammatical mistakes that seem to have been classed in the lexical category. For example,

> a huge of them are from the manual labor market

A clause requires a noun or pronoun as subject, and “huge” is an adjective. I think what you mean is

> most such tasks involve manual labor

For another example

> because … once is automatic the task is performed with minimal error vs a human

Here a subject is again omitted. The more apt word is “automated” rather than “automatic,” and comparing “minimal error” and a person is comparing non-comparable things. What is meant is

> because … a repetitive process is performed with far fewer errors by a machine than by a person.

Your first passage is filled with poor word choices.

> The data is not structured as it was accorded in the beginning.

What is meant is

> The data is not structured as initially specified

or

> The data is not structured according to the initial specifications

As for

> We have confirmation

it is less ambiguous to write

> We get confirmation

As for

> There are some important features for the ML model that  are not available at the moment we need to do the prediction

I cannot even guess what that means.

So my assessment would have been a small number of errors in grammar and punctuation and a large number of poor choices in vocabulary.

Comment: In written English the phrase *...which would allow us to **develop smoothly** the model...* would be written *...which would allow us to **smoothly develop** the model...*

Comment: @EllieK-Don'tsupporther I agree although, as a matter of style,  I’d prefer to end the sentence with “smoothly” rather than split the infinitive.

Comment: The data is not structured *as agreed* in the beginning. "There are some important features for the ML model that are not available at the moment we need to do the prediction" is trying to say: There are some important features of the ML model that were not available when we needed make predictions.

Comment: @Lambie Yes, “agreed” is quite nice, concise. If your interpretation of the other sentence is correct (and it well may be), then “were not disclosed” or “have been added” would be better than “were not available,” and “when we needed to estimate time for completion” rather than “to make predictions.” But kudos for extracting meaning from that mishmash.

Comment: I would love to go in their and edit the whole thing but I daren't given the sticklers for rules here. Cheers, Jeff.

Comment: Plus it would be interminable! But the main issue remains: the vocabulary is consistently slightly off. Cheers.

Comment: @JeffMorrow Maybe **we need to do the prediction** means "we'll have to guess what they are"?

Comment: @PeterJennings Yes, that is exactly the problem: predictions of what, and are they predictions or estimates or guesses.

Comment: Whoops, go in **there**.